# IllegalState At least one issue expected in Sonar custom plugin

Tags: java, maven, plugins, sonarqube

I am very new to Sonar.
I am trying to make my own plugin for sonar. After downloading plugin example, I make it eclipse ready using mvn eclipse:eclipse and import to workspace. It is compiling fine.
But I need to add my own Rule files to it.
For that purpose, I have created 2 files.

`MyCustomNLSRuleTest .java`

```
package org.sonar.samples.java.checks;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.sonar.java.checks.verifier.JavaCheckVerifier;

public class MyCustomNLSRuleTest {

  @Test
  public void check() {
    // Verifies that the check will raise the adequate issues with the expected message.
    // In the test file, lines which should raise an issue have been commented out
    // by using the following syntax: "// Noncompliant {{EXPECTED_MESSAGE}}"
    JavaCheckVerifier.verify("src/test/files/MissingCheck.java", new MyCustomSubscriptionRule());
  }
}
```

The actual rule is provided to me in the following java file which looks like below -

`MissingCheck.java`

```
public class MissingCheck extends Check 
{

    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> lineStringMap;

    @Override
    public void beginTree(DetailAST aRootAST) {
        super.beginTree(aRootAST);
        lineStringMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int[] getDefaultTokens() {
        return new int[] { TokenTypes.STRING_LITERAL};
    }

    @Override
    public void visitToken(DetailAST ast) {
        DetailAST parent = ast.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            DetailAST grandpa = parent.getParent();
            if (isAnnotation(grandpa.getType())) {
                return;
            }
        }
        Integer count = lineStringMap.get(ast.getLineNo());
        if (count == null) {
            count = new Integer(1);
        } else {
            count++;
        }
        FileContents contents = getFileContents();

        String[] line = contents.getLines();
        if (line.length >= ast.getLineNo()) {
            String l = line[ast.getLineNo() - 1];
            if (!l.contains("$NON-NLS-" + count + "$")) {
                log(ast.getLineNo(), "String_Not_Externalized", new Object[] { ast.getText() });
            }
        }
        lineStringMap.put(ast.getLineNo(), count);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if type is an annotation.
     * @param type to check
     * @return <code>true</code> if type is an annotation.
     */
    private boolean isAnnotation(int type) {
        return (type >= TokenTypes.ANNOTATION_DEF && type <= TokenTypes.ANNOTATION_ARRAY_INIT);
    }
}
```

But, I am trying to do mvn clean package this project, it gives me error:

```
Results :

Tests in error: 
  MyCustomNLSRuleTest.check:13 » IllegalState At least one issue expected

Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any idea, how I can add a new rule in the plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it seems that you are very far from what you are supposed to do when writing custom rules for the java plugin... A few questions first:

- Did you actually tried to have a look at the dedicated page from the SonarQube confluence? http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Custom+Rules+for+Java
- Did you actually look at the following links before trying to write a rule?

  - [The rule already implemented in the example project](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/java-custom-rules/src/main/java/org/sonar/samples/java/checks),
  - [How they are tested](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/java-custom-rules/src/test/java/org/sonar/samples/java/checks),
  - [With which test files](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/java-custom-rules/src/test/files),
  - [How they are registered in the custom plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/plugins/java-custom-rules/src/main/java/org/sonar/samples/java/MyJavaFileCheckRegistrar.java),
  - The comments from the unit test you are actually writing.

Now... Let's start by explaining to you what you are currently doing, as apparently it's not clear at all.

- You created a test file called `MyCustomNLSRuleTest.java`, which should theoretically correspond to a rule called `MyCustomNLSRule`. Note that it's probably not the case, as you are saying that the rule *is provided to you* in the `MissingCheck.java` file.
- Your unit test uses `JavaCheckVerifier` to verify that the file provided as argument, `"src/test/files/MissingCheck.java"`, will raise all the expected issues when playing the rule `MyCustomSubscriptionRule` against it.

At this point, you are **not testing at all** your `MissingCheck`, but using it as data for the `MyCustomSubscriptionRule` rule... And it's probably your main issue.

However, if this is actually  really what you are trying to achieve, it means that:

- You modified the rule `MyCustomSubscriptionRule` to have a custom behavior, different from the one from the original example project.
- When executing it on the file `MissingCheck.java`, the check is supposed to raise issue (with the line having issue being commented out with `// Noncompliant {{expected message}}`)
- Your custom rule **does not work**, as it apparently raised no issue at all when playing the test.

Please look at all the links provided above to see how custom rules works, what is available in the java plugin API, and what you can achieve with it.